# How to consume any xml and store it db in grails with REST

Tags: xml, rest, grails

With a documentation in `GRAILS` about `REST` services I can create simple *REST web application*.
In *GRAILS* with *REST* service i would like (*POST* method) to **get ANY xml** (it means xml can be really any) and store it as a *string* in `DB`.
And later to return it (as is) by *GET* method from `DB`.

How to do it?
BTW. in `SOAPUI 5.0` (*mock REST service*) I has implemented it with 10 strings of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class XmlController {
    def upload() {
        def msg = request.reader.text
        // save all you want
    }
}
```